# appending two lists results in call by reference

Tags: python, list, pass-by-reference

While trying to make multiple lists with various elements, I run into a problem where the previously appended elements also change.

```
import random
def randArr(length):
    num = []
    for i in range(length):
        num.append(random.randint(-100, 100))
    return num

l1 = []
l2 = []
for i in range(3):
    l2.clear()
    l2.append(randArr(1))
    l1.append(l2)
    print('l1', l1)
    print('l2', l2)
    print()
```

gives

```
l1 [[[-8]]]
l2 [[-8]]

l1 [[[43]], [[43]]]
l2 [[43]]

l1 [[[-96]], [[-96]], [[-96]]]
l2 [[-96]]
```

I am aware that I could replace the 12th line to say
`l2 = randArr(1)`instead, however I **need to use append** for various reasons.

Any advice on how to get around this?

Comment: Replace `l2.clear` with `l2 = []`. Using `list.clear()` means you're just appending the same mutated `list` to `l1` multiple times.

Comment: This is not call by reference. Python **never** uses call by reference (nor call by value, for that matter).

Comment: Anyway, you *keep appeending the same list*: `l1.append(l2)`, so of course, `l1` becomes a list with multiple references *to the same list*. Just create a new list instead of `.clear`ing and appending the same list

Comment: Or maybe use ```l1 += l2``` in the next (13th) line.

Comment: Creating a new list or using `l2 = []` worked great, Thank you.
For the final program, a combination of using `l2 = []` and `l1.append(l2.copy())` made it work